# Query a 4-levels deep list hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual List<FirstChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class FirstChild
{
    public virtual List<SecondChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class SecondChild
{
    public virtual List<ThirdChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class ThirdChild
{
    public List<FourthCild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class FourthCild
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

To get a specific ThirdChild from an instance of BaseClass, I was trying with something like this:

```
using (MyDb context = new MyDb())
{
    context.BaseClass.Where(u => u.username == username).FirstOrDefault()
    .FirstChild.Where(f => f.SomeId == idReceived).FirstOrDefault()
    .SecondChild.Where(s => s.MyProperty.Identifier == identifierReceived).FirstOrDefault()
    .ThirdChild.Where(t => t.Identifier == thirdIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is this the shortest/cleanest way of doing this? I would think there's an easier way, but I'm new to Entity Framework. I don't have any data to test this for now, since I'm still modelling it. The context class looks like this:

```
public class MyDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseClass> Base { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FirstChild> First { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SecondChild> Second { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ThirdChild> Third { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Define and use `Parent` navigation property at each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `one-to-many` relationships. You already provided so called **navigation property** at the **one** side, but you need also to provide the similar at the **many** side, like this

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual List<FirstChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class FirstChild
{
    public virtual BaseClass Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SecondChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class SecondChild
{
    public virtual FirstChild Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ThirdChild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class ThirdChild
{
    public virtual SecondChild Parent { get; set; }
    public List<FourthCild> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class FourthCild
{
    public virtual ThirdChild Parent { get; set; }
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can start the query directly from the level you want

```
context.Third.Where(t => t.Identifier == thirdIdentifier
    && t.Parent.MyProperty.Identifier == identifierReceived
    && t.Parent.Parent.SomeId == idReceived
    && t.Parent.Parent.Parent.username == username)
```

Comment: I'm selecting your answer since you took the time to explain with code directly the navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be going about this slightly backwards and your multiple 'FirstOrDefault' calls may cause you some performance issues, as each one will hit the DB.

Perhaps you need somthing more like:

```
var target = (from tc in context.Third
   where tc.Identifier == thirdIdentifier
   && tc.SecondChild.MyProperty.Identifer == identifierReceived
   && tc.SecondChild.FirstChild.someId == idReceived
   && tc.SecondChild.FirstChild.Base.username == username
   select tc).FirstOrDefault();
```

i.e. thinking similarly to how you would do this if you were writing SQL directly, select from ThirdChild, join up the hierarchy and filter in the where clause.

---

Note - this assumes a one-many relationship between each parent and its children.

Comment: @Paddy  Two of those boolean checks are assignment operators in your example.

Comment: How would I go about referring to the secondchild from the third child? Using a `virtual ParentType` property?

Comment: @zackery.fix thanks.  Switching between VB.net and C# today.  Constant error when typing...

Comment: @cFrozenDeath - Assuming your DB model, SecondChild has collection of ThirdChilds, then I would expect your ThirdChild to have a SecondChild 'parent' property, so yes, as you described, assuming an EF code first setup.

Comment: One last thing, you are missing a `select tc` after the last where condition, otherwise VS complains "a query body must end with a select statement"